# How not to update updated_at timestamp when changing an Eloquent attribute in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I am wondering how I can update a model where some attributes are not watched for isDirty() or updated_at. I have one field in this case which needs to be updated, without touching the updated_at timestamp.

I cannot find how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the timestamps when doing your changes.

Like this:

```
function saveDudeWithoutTimeStamps($userId) {

    $user = User::find($userId);
    $user->timestamps = false; // this one should do the trick
    $user->email = 'blabla@example.com';
    $user->save();

}
```